# Where does Spring Security stores my session data by default?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, jsessionid

I'm currently trying to implemente some basic security structure to my Spring Boot project, but I can't find an really concrete answer to what is going on in the authentication process. Basically, I just followed this tutorial:

https://leaks.wanari.com/2017/11/28/how-to-make-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-with-spring-security

An it seems to be using the default Spring Security protocols and stuff, i really only implemented a custom filter where my code checks MongoDB for an existing user, and the thing works as expected.

The thing is, Postman tells me that whenever I do a successful login I receive a JSESSIONID cookie, and this cookie is used on get requests, for example. If there is a SESSION ID, I assume that Spring somehow knows how to map ID to users, but how? I haven't set up any DB configuration for that, and Spring seems to store that state somewhere. How can I access it, or change to a DB on which access I have control of?

Comment: You can see this thread for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25800632/921684

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save sessions to database, you can add `org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc` dependencty. You can choose sql file from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc) for your database and create tables.

Comment: I appreciate the tip, but I'm currently on MongoDB, so no SQL will be really useful right now. My question is more related to know the inner workings of Spring Security's session management, and how to override that with my own session management DB.

Comment: Hi, did anyone find the answer to the question ?